# SQL query throws error C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, methods

I have created a database and display the data in a gridview. I am trying to enable a method that searches for an employee's name and returns the results.

The following SQL displays correct rows when the EXACT NAME is entered. -

```
SELECT personID, name, address, phoneNumber, age FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like @name
```

**I want to be able to display rows where the name is correct and partially correct.**

I have tried the following SQL -

```
SELECT personID, name, address, phoneNumber, age FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like @name%
```

But it throws the error "no overload for method 'searchName' takes 2 arguments".

When the "search" button is clicked, the following code is executed:

```
        this.personTableAdapter.searchName(this.personDataSet.person,
        searchTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Is searchName derived from a stored procedure? Is that something you added to your table adapter? It obviously doesn't take 2 parameters. You probably don't need the first one.

Comment: searchName is the name of the Method I have created with the SQL  
"SELECT personID, name, address, phoneNumber, age FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like @name% "

Comment: It has been added to the table adapter.

Comment: @KiraBorke this is the reason why your query broke up `Like @name%`

Comment: no overload for method 'searchName' takes 2 arguments is a compiler error that means that there isn't a compiled method that takes two arguments try it with out the this.personDataSet.employee argument.

Comment: I'm trying this for the "search" button: this.employeeTableAdapter.searchName(searchTextBox.Text);

Answer (score 6):

modify your `LIKE` into concatenation of the keyword and the `%`

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE name LIKE @name + '%'
```

Comment: For "partially correct" you might want to go `LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@name)) + '%'`. Remove the trim functions if spaces are of no concern.

Answer (score 1):

could you try doing the LIKE query like this

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT personID, name, address, phoneNumber, age FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like @name");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name + "%");
```

Comment: the op is using table adapter

Comment: Ah, I see. My bad, early in the morning. :-)

Answer (score 0):

i think you will be using a textbox or something like that to get the name the user is searching for.
When you read it you may use something like that:

```
string _Name = "%" + searchTextBox.Text + "%";
```

then pass the string variable to your script.

```
    SELECT personID, name, address, phoneNumber, age FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like @name
```

hope this helps, it works fine with me.